# Find whether id matches and substitute using Case Hive query

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table called "**Scan**" customer transactions where an individual_id appears once for every different transaction and contains column like **scan_id**.
I have another table called **ids** which contains random individual_ids sampled from **Scan** Table

I would like to join **ids** with **scan** and get a single record of ids and scan_id if it matches certain values.

Suppose data is like below

**Scan table**

```
Ids          scan_id
----        ------
1           100
1           111
1           1000
2           100
2           111
3           124
4           1000
4           111
```

```
Ids table

id
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want below output i.e if scan_id matches either 100 or 1000

```
Id        MT
------    ------
1          1
2          1
3          0
4          1
```

I executed below query and got error

```
select MT, d.individual_id
from  
(
  select 
    CASE 
      when scan_id in (90069421,53971306,90068594,136739913,195308160) then 1 
      ELSE 0
    END as MT
  from scan cs join ids r
 on cs.individual_id = r.individual_id
where 
        base_div_nbr =1 
        and 
        country_code ='US' 
        and
         retail_channel_code=1 
         and visit_date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31'
) as d
group by individual_id;
```

I would appreciate any suggestions or help with regard to this Hive query. If there is an efficient way of getting this job done. Let me know.

Comment: Your question mentions two columns but your code mentions a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `group by`:

```
select s.individual_id,
      max(case when s.scan_id in (100, 1000) then 1 else 0 end) as mt
from scan s 
group by s.individual_id;
```

The `ids` table doesn't seem to be needed for this query.